# IEnumerable<T> and Take(x) issue?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, .net-4.0

*(using Entity Framework)*

when i write :

```
IEnumerable<string> q = customers /*EF entity*/
.Select (c => c.Name.ToUpper())
.OrderBy (n => n)
```

the c# compiler knows how to emit expression trees which in turn , the sql execute :

```
SELECT UPPER (Name) FROM Customer ORDER BY UPPER (Name)
```

*notice also the `order by` clause is there*

but

i saw ***[this link](http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/iqueryable-vs-ienumerable)***  :

he wrote :

```
IEnumerable<employee> emp = 
         dc.Employees.Where(x => x.Desc.StartsWith("soft"));
emp = emp.Take(1);
```

after investigating the final query he saw :

```
SELECT [t0].[Id], [t0].[Name], [t0].[Address], [t0].[Desc] AS [Desc]
FROM [dbo].[Employee] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[Desc] LIKE @p0
```

notice there is **no** `top` clause

why is that ?

shouldn't `Take(x)` be added to the query ?

will writing it like this :

```
IEnumerable<employee> emp = 
         (dc.Employees.Where(x => x.Desc.StartsWith("soft"))).Take(1);
```

would added the TOP clause to the query being sent to SQL ?

what is going here ?

*( I already know that `take` is not a deferred execution)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extension methods such as `Take()` are static methods, and as such they are resolved at compile time.

The compile time type of emp is `IEnumerable<employee>` (because it was explicitly declared as one), so the compiler picks `Enumerable.Take` instead of `Queryable.Take`, which does not perform any query translation.

If you would have been lazy and would just have used **`var`** instead of a type name:

```
var emp = dc.Employees.Where(x => x.Desc.StartsWith("soft"));
emp = emp.Take(1);
```

it would have worked, because the compiler would have picked `IQueryable<employee>` for emp (because the expression you initialize it with is of that type), and thus `Queryable.Take` for the second call.

Comment: if i write
 `IEnumerable<employee> emp = 
         dc.Employees.Where(x => x.Desc.StartsWith("soft"));
         emp = emp.OrderBy(c=>c.x);`
will the expression in sql execution *will include the order by clause* ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir No it won't, for the same reason. The compiler looks at your variable and sees it is an `IEnumerable<employee>`. Because of that it decides that `Enumerable.OrderBy` is the best match, because it takes an `IEnumerable<T>` as parameter.

Comment: regarding `var`.... the initialization is `ienumerable` or `iqueryable` ? apparently it's an `Iqueryable` but it could be also `Ienumerable`.... what actually makes the decision ?

Comment: The decision is made by the expression used to initialize the variable. `dc.Employees` implements `IQueryable`, so the following `.Where` also returns an `IQueryable`. The compiler just follows the method calls on `dc.Employees.Where(x => x.Desc.StartsWith("soft"))` and the type that comes out at the end (after `Where`) is the type of emp.

Comment: @RoyiNamir In this case, IQueryable is preferred.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Actually, `ObjectQuery<T>.Where` even returns another `ObjectQuery<T>`, so `emp` would actually be `ObjectQuery<T>`, which provides its own set of Linq methods ([see MSDN for more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355149)). Because those methods are instance methods, and instance methods are always preferred over Linq methods, those will be used.

Answer (score 9):

If you added `Take(1)` to the first expression, it would be on `IQueryable<T>`, and thus added to the SQL. But since you converted `IQueryable<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>`, `Take(1)` is done in memory: `IEnumerable<T>` has an identically-named [`Take()` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx), and as far as compiler knows, `emp` is `IEnumerable<T>`, not `IQueryable<T>`, so the in-memory version gets called.

Comment: +1 Always thought you had to `.ToList`, didn't know you could move it to in-memory by just declaring it `IEnumerable`.  Good to know!

Comment: I dont understand why adding Take(1) to the first code here , will make it as Iqueryable...? Ienumerable also have take(1)...?

Comment: @RoyiNamir `emp` is an `IQueryable<T>` to start with, but it is also `IEnumerable<T>`. If you change `emp`'s declaration to `IQueryable<employee> emp` or to `var emp`, the two-line version will work as well. But you tell the compiler to forget about the fact that it's `IQueryable<T>` by declaring it `IEnumerabme<T>`, so the compiler has to comply.

Comment: im lost... let me see.... if i write
 `IEnumerable<employee> emp = 
         dc.Employees.Where(x => x.Desc.StartsWith("soft"));
         emp = emp.OrderBy(c=>c.x);`
will the expression in sql execution *will include the order by clause* ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir Oops, I wrote `IEnumerabme` instead of `IQueryable`! Too late to edit it now.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Stack Overflow does not let you edit your comments after five minutes.